# how to know whether the remote end closed the socket using send system call?

Tags: linux, socketserver

the send() system call succeeds for the first time even if the remote end closed the connection.
If i send again, then sigpipe will be generated.
I don't want to use recv system call to know whether remote end closed the connection.

So can someone tell me how can i detect whether the remote end closed the connection using only send system call ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is call `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` to avoid receiving `SIGPIPE` on `send()` or, on Linux, pass `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag to `send()`. Having done that, `send()` will not generate `SIGPIPE` signal when a peer has disconnected, but rather return -1 with `errno == EPIPE`.

Sending `SIGPIPE` is historical behaviour of `write()` function. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/write.html

> `EPIPE` An attempt is made to write to a pipe or `FIFO` that is not open for reading by any process, or that only has one end open. A `SIGPIPE` signal shall also be sent to the thread.

Originally it was created for shell pipes (like `cmd | other_cmd`). When `ctrl-c` is pressed during shell pipe execution  only the last process in the pipe receives `SIGINT` and terminates. To terminate other processes in the pipe `SIGPIPE` is sent to the process trying to `write()` into `STDOUT` whose reader has already terminated.

Comment: Is this because, send() will get preempted for the kernel to go process the software interrupt (invoke the signal handler subsequently); following which some systems might try to restart the execution of the system call which got preempted i.e. send() in this case ? Basically the program could loop ?